# why is My Ingress Ip same as Minikube Ip. I am not able to access the Minikube Ip in my Broswer

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I have created a Service as Load Balancer and tried accessing the service using Minikube tunnel. It is working.

When I tried creating Ingress for the service i get the IP as same as minikube IP and not the tunnel IP.

My ingress Controller is of type `NodePort`

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default                kubernetes                           ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      18h
default                springboot                           NodePort    10.103.228.107   <none>        8090:32389/TCP               16h
ingress-nginx          ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.98.92.81      <none>        80:31106/TCP,443:32307/TCP   17h
ingress-nginx          ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.99.224.119    <none>        443/TCP                      17h
kube-system            kube-dns                             ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       18h
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper            ClusterIP   10.100.23.18     <none>        8000/TCP                     16h
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard                 ClusterIP   10.98.172.252    <none>        80/TCP                       16h
```

I tunnel this using:

```
minikube service  ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx --url
* Starting tunnel for service ingress-nginx-controller.
|---------------|--------------------------|-------------|------------------------|
|   NAMESPACE   |           NAME           | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|---------------|--------------------------|-------------|------------------------|
| ingress-nginx | ingress-nginx-controller |             | http://127.0.0.1:58628 |
|               |                          |             | http://127.0.0.1:58629 |
|---------------|--------------------------|-------------|------------------------|
http://127.0.0.1:58628
http://127.0.0.1:58629
! Because you are using a Docker driver on windows, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

I get the Url as  http://127.0.0.1:58628.

I now apply ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingresstest
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "ravi.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: springboot
            port:
              number: 8090
```

But the ingress addressed is exposed in

```
kubectl get ingress
NAME          CLASS    HOSTS      ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
ingresstest   <none>   ravi.com   192.168.49.2   80      64m
```

I need the tunnel URL in ingress

Comment: Hello @user2924500, please provide more details:  Which ingress do you use? Please also attach your configuration in .yaml files. Do you have some errors? What do want to achive?

Comment: I have edited the description

Comment: I am using      ingress-nginx-controller

Comment: When i tunnel my service i am able to access. But not able to access via Ingress. (Ingress Address is same as Minikube IP) . I am using --driver=docker

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot have the tunnel URL in your ingress. Ingress is working as expected.

You can add [minikube ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#minikube) by commmand: `minikube addons enable ingress`.  After enabling ingress addon it is specifically stated that: `After the addon is enabled, please run "minikube tunnel" and your ingress resources would be available at "127.0.0.1"`. This [tunnel](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/tunnel/#minikube-tunnel) creates a route to services deployed with type LoadBalancer and sets their Ingress to their ClusterIP. You can find more info [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/).

So you can install ingress, but unfortunately it won't work the way you want it.

You should also know, that Minikube is mainly used for testing and learning purposes so some of it's features might not be ideal.

Comment: mikiube addons enable ingress failed so i did

Comment: kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-0.31.1/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml

Comment: I am able to access via the tunnel URL of Load balancer service http://127.0.0.1:8090/. But not through ingress URL ravi,com

Comment: My app  Service and Ingress  loks like this

Comment: default                springboot                           LoadBalancer   10.101.140.68   127.0.0.1     8090:32038/TCP               4m21s
ingress-nginx          ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort       10.96.22.191    <none>        80:31005/TCP,443:31302/TCP   38h

Comment: My ingress controleer ip is 127.0.0.1 and port is 80:30972/TCP,443:30290/TCP.  when i give 127.0.0.1:80 it is not accessible

Comment: Try to remove domain name from your `host:` in yaml file. It should be `host:` instead of `host: ravi.com`. The ingress controller will direct the traffic to your service.

Comment: Please do not write a new comment each time you press ENTER. Use the "Edit comment" button to add content (and mark tech text with back-ticks: *\`your config\`*); or edit the original question and add details there; or continue [inside a chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new) – However, related to your issue, your OS need to be told where to look for `ravi.com`; if you don't add any rule in `/etc/hosts` the OS won't access Minikube but will make a DNS request same way as for a normal internet domain.