# Flask application on Minikube refuse connection using ingress

Tags: python, nginx, flask, kubernetes, minikube

I have single replica pod running python flask application on port 5000. Below is my configuration and details.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-120 ~]$ cat tree_management/application/*.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tree-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tree-management
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tree-management
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tree-management
        image: tree-management
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tree-ingress
  #  annotations:
  #    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: local.ec.org
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /tree
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: tree-service
            port:
              number: 5000

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tree-service
spec:
        #  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: tree-management
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

Application is running fine inside pod as When I do kubectl exec in pod to hit api url then it gives me output.
Below is some kubectl output.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-120 ~]$ minikube service list
|----------------------|------------------------------------|--------------|---------------------------|
|      NAMESPACE       |                NAME                | TARGET PORT  |            URL            |
|----------------------|------------------------------------|--------------|---------------------------|
| default              | kubernetes                         | No node port |
| default              | tree-service                       | No node port |
| ingress-nginx        | ingress-nginx-controller           | http/80      | http://192.168.49.2:31893 |
|                      |                                    | https/443    | http://192.168.49.2:30453 |
| ingress-nginx        | ingress-nginx-controller-admission | No node port |
| kube-system          | kube-dns                           | No node port |
| kubernetes-dashboard | dashboard-metrics-scraper          | No node port |
| kubernetes-dashboard | kubernetes-dashboard               | No node port |
|----------------------|------------------------------------|--------------|---------------------------|
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-120 ~]$ kubectl get svc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE              NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default                kubernetes                           ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      39h
default                tree-service                         ClusterIP   10.99.136.46     <none>        5000/TCP                     14m
ingress-nginx          ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.96.58.167     <none>        80:31893/TCP,443:30453/TCP   21h
ingress-nginx          ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.103.107.214   <none>        443/TCP                      21h
kube-system            kube-dns                             ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       39h
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper            ClusterIP   10.98.246.45     <none>        8000/TCP                     39h
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard                 ClusterIP   10.98.103.55     <none>        80/TCP                       39h
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-120 ~]$ minikube ip
192.168.49.2
```

I have added host entry in local as well with minikube IP. When I try to access my flask application using nodeIp it is not working. This is what I get when I hit URL

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-120 ~]$ curl http://192.168.49.2/tree
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is log from nginx ingress

```
2021/05/24 07:59:44 [error] 298#298: *20007 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.49.1, server: local.ec.org, request: "GET /tree HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.5:5000/tree", host: "local.ec.org"
2021/05/24 07:59:44 [error] 298#298: *20007 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.49.1, server: local.ec.org, request: "GET /tree HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.5:5000/tree", host: "local.ec.org"
2021/05/24 07:59:44 [error] 298#298: *20007 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.49.1, server: local.ec.org, request: "GET /tree HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.5:5000/tree", host: "local.ec.org"
192.168.49.1 - - [24/May/2021:07:59:44 +0000] "GET /tree HTTP/1.1" 502 150 "-" "curl/7.61.1" 84 0.000 [default-tree-service-5000] [] 172.17.0.5:5000, 172.17.0.5:5000, 172.17.0.5:5000 0, 0, 0 0.000, 0.000, 0.000 502, 502, 502 bd34da31533e0f3393ff490efe37a90d
```

Also tried with below combination of CURL but it all fails.

```
  curl http://local.ec.org:5000
  curl http://local.ec.org
  curl http://local.ec.org/tree
  curl http://local.ec.org/tree -H local.ec.org
  curl http://local.ec.org -H local.ec.org
  curl http://local.ec.org/ -H local.ec.org
  curl http://local.ec.org/tree -H local.ec.org
  curl http://192.168.49.2:5000/tree -H Host:local.ec.org
```

Can you please help what's wrong here?

**Update 1**
After doing some config changes, I can see if I hit below URL then request is going to nginx but not sure why it returns 502 bad gateway.

```
curl http://local.ec.org/tree
```

Error on Nginx. I dont know why nginx is failing to connect upstream?

```
2021/05/24 13:01:58 [error] 447#447: *168693 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.49.1, server: local.ec.org, request: "GET /tree HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.5:5000/tree", host: "local.ec.org"
192.168.49.1 - - [24/May/2021:13:01:58 +0000] "GET /tree HTTP/1.1" 502 150 "-" "curl/7.61.1" 84 0.001 [default-tree-service-5000] [] 172.17.0.5:5000, 172.17.0.5:5000, 172.17.0.5:5000 0, 0, 0 0.000, 0.000, 0.000 502, 502, 502 dff2ca8a83f9d2237300b6d46f978e43
2021/05/24 13:01:58 [error] 447#447: *168693 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.49.1, server: local.ec.org, request: "GET /tree HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.5:5000/tree", host: "local.ec.org"
2021/05/24 13:01:58 [error] 447#447: *168693 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.49.1, server: local.ec.org, request: "GET /tree HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.5:5000/tree", host: "local.ec.org"
```

Comment: Have you tried `http://192.168.49.2:31893/tree`? That's the URL that minikube actually gave you.

Comment: @coderanger Yes, Just tried it but nginx gives 404..

Comment: Hi @AshifNataliya, I can see in your `ingress nginx-controller`. Did you use `minikube tunnel`?  If you want to have ingress controller in Minikube, You can add [minikube ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#minikube) by commmand: `minikube addons enable ingress`. After enabling ingress addon it is specifically stated that: `After the addon is enabled, please run "minikube tunnel" and your ingress resources would be available at "127.0.0.1"`. Look at the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67515663/).

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak Yes I alrady have ingress addon enabled. I didnt run minikube tunnel before. I just tried it but its not helping.  tried curl with 127.0.0.1 as well but still failing

Comment: I can see, that you are using ec2 instance. Maybe it will be better if you could use AWS EKS. Bear in mind that Minikube is mainly used for testing and learning purposes so some of it's features might not be ideal. Look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1045312/kubernates-on-prem-502-bad-gateway). I found very similar issue. And here is also a [documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/) how to access apps step by step using Minikube.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak Actually my requirement is to use ingress controller to access service from outside cluster and hence I am using this. This is only for demo purpose and certainly not using this in prod environment.

Comment: 502 means there are no ready pods. Check if your pod is crashing on startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue and culprit was Flask application. In order to troubleshoot issue, I have logged in to the Flask Pod and executed below command.

```
netstat -tupln
```

This explained me that application is listening on port 5000 but it by default allows connection only from 127.0.0.1. (i.e from self). This is because I started application using app.run() command. I had to change this command as below.

```
# Run flask app.
app.run(
host="0.0.0.0",
port=5000
    )
```

This allows connection from any host (i.e. 0.0.0.0).

**Note:** This is a demo application and hence I have allowed from 0.0.0.0 but it is not recommended to do in production environment.